# Add hours in PHP

Tags: php

I have hours in the following format from the database and trying to find out the way to add them the while loop.

```
ID               Hours
1                2:23:40
2                4:20:30
3                1:10:20


while ($stmt->fetch()) {
$totalhours += $working_hours;
}

echo $totalhours;
```

Any ideas how can I add them so that I get the hours inclusive of minutes and seconds?

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Spoonnz solution is good. If you can modify the actual SQL, then use `SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_field))` to have mysql do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert everything to seconds, add the seconds together, then convert that to hours etc. One easy way is this. Note it won't work so well with a total > 24 hours.

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $totalhours += strtotime($working_hours);
}

$totalhours = date('H:i:s', $totalhours);
```